# Django: converting csv file to ofx doesn't work when i put the source = request.FILES

Tags: django, csv, django-models, django-views, ofx

I need some help please from 2 days am trying to convert a csv file of an ofx file , i have suceeded to do that but the thing just work when i specify a file and not something general what i mean :

this code work perfect :

```
def UploadFile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BlogForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
          form.save()
          ofx = OFX(mapping)
          records = read_csv("/home/mariana/django_project/media/test.csv", has_header=True)
          groups = ofx.gen_groups(records)
          trxns = ofx.gen_trxns(groups)
          cleaned_trxns = ofx.clean_trxns(trxns)
          data = utils.gen_data(cleaned_trxns)
          content = it.chain([ofx.header(), ofx.gen_body(data), ofx.footer()])
          with open ("/home/mariana/django_project/media/testt.ofx", 'w') as f:
            res = write(f, IterStringIO(content))
            print("sucess")
    else:
        form = BlogForm()
    context = {
            'form':form,
        }
    return render(request, 'pages/Upload.html', context)
```

this is my models.py :

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    csv_file = models.FileField(null = True, upload_to='files_csv')
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=20, null = True)
    urlpatterns = [
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Blog, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

the thing doesn't work if i go that in general what i mean is if i modify :

```
records = read_csv("/home/mariana/django_project/media/test.csv", has_header=True)
```

------>

```
records = read_csv(request.FILES, has_header=True)
```

---> it doesn't work and give me an error(`expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not MultiValueDict`) , why this !!! why when i put request.FILES doesn't work

Comment: Show us your forms.py and your form's html please.